# Getting the value of the first cell within a button click in the third cell

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have this snippet in an .aspx file:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Ops</th>
    </tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
</table>
<button id="buttonTest" onclick="updateTable()">Test Button</button>
```

In an Javascript file attached to this one I have the following method:

```
function updateTable(data) {
    parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    // Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    //Deletes all the rows
    deleteTableRows(table);

    //Inserts the new data
    for (i = 0; i < parsedData.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

        // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

        // Add some text to the new cells:
        tAID = parsedData[i].TipoAtributoID;
        cell1.innerHTML = tAID;
        cell2.innerHTML = parsedData[i].Nome;
        cell3.innerHTML = '<button onclick="deleteTipoAtributo('+tAID+')" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>';
        cell3.innerHTML += '<button onclick="deleteTipoAtributo('+tAID+')" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>';
        }
}
```

As you can see, I am passing the first cell ID through the `click` event. This does seem sketchy to me but I am unable to find a better approach. What is the best option here so that the function that gets called on `onclick` can find out what is the content of the first cell of the row in which the button is?

The method to update the table content is going to be called multiple times, so hard coding the buttons in the html is (I think) out of the options.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the button is guaranteed to be a direct child of the `<td>`, you can retrieve the first cell in the row this way:

1. Go to the button's parent `<td>`: `this.parentNode`
2. Go to the `<td>`'s parent `<tr>`: `td.parentNode`
3. Get the `<tr>`'s first child node: `tr.firstChild`
4. Get the first cell's html content: `td.innerHTML`

```
function onBtnClick(e) {
  // note that here 'this' is the element on which the function was called
  var firstCell = this.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild;

  deleteTipoAtributo(firstCell.innerHTML); // call your function
}
```

Now you can assign the onClick function to `onBtnClick` without any args:

```
<button onclick="onBtnClick" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

Also, to avoid repetition and setting the cell content via HTML string, you can create a button DOM node and insert it into the cell using `.appendChild()`.